# Hello World php page has 404 status

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, fastcgi, lighttpd

I have the following PHP code in index.php:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

Hello World is printed on the screen, but the Status code is 404. There is no header() function as you can see. I've looked at php.ini and the LightTPD configuration file but everything seems ok. I'm running LightTPD for Windows and PHP in FastCGI. What are the probable causes to this issue?

Comment: What makes you think the status code is 404?

Comment: Are you using any rewrites, or any other modules in Lighttpd for that matter?

Comment: @Locke Please show us the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Where you think the file is, it isn't there. Are you able to navigate to an html file in the same directory? The 404 isn't a "that page isn't rendering correctly in php" message, it's a "I don't find that file at all" message

Comment: Yes, I am able to navigate to an html file just fine and with correct status code and I can also navigate to the PHP file but the status code is incorrect and I didn't modify it in any way.

Comment: I have not used LightTPD, I use XAMPP for my windows development of php. It sounds like PHP just isn't configured correctly if you are certain it is a 404 and you are looking in the correct place.

Comment: I don't know if there is a setting in php.ini that causes this behaviour. My doc_root is set correctly, uncommented the extension directory for windows and the MySQL extensions, and all the other options are the default production ini values.